# Unit Testing: Directive with Dynamic Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am running across an issue when trying to use an unusual method to grab templates for my page-content. I have abstracted it but suffice to say that the code works fine but the testing is throwing up some issues. I have listed my directive below:

Directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        page: '=pageCode',
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        $http.get('templates/' + scope.page + '.html', {cache: $templateCache})
            .success(function(html) {
                element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
            });
    }
};
```

Basically, when this directive is called with the `page-code` attribute, it grabs it and pulls in a specific partial for that page content. I have tried mocking out a `$scope` to contain the code but that wasn't working so I am hardcoding the `data-page-code="404"` for now. The test is as follows:

Directive Test:

```
it('should compile and pass through the scope', function() {
    mockDirectiveHtml= '<div data-page-content data-page-code="404"></div>';
    mockTemplateHtml= '<h1>Hi</h1>';
    $httpBackend.expectGET('templates/404.html').respond(mockTemplateHtml);

    pageContentHtml= $compile(mockDirectiveHtml)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(pageContentHtml.html()).toEqual('<h1>Hi</h1>');
});
```

However when this runs, the console is telling me it is trying to hit `GET('templates/undefined.html')`. Now I am unsure if I have things in the right order, or if that is even the solution but has anyone came across something like this in the past? I assume the directive is running before the attributes are passed to it so when it comes to grab `templates/' + 'scope.code'` that value is undefined.